# How do you pass json data from one page to another to reference the same row of data?

Tags: javascript, json

I am pulling address location information from a google spreadsheet and using it to create buttons.  When you click on a button it then should open and populate the data for that location in a new page or if need into a dialog box.

How do you pass the information to a new page and complete the if statement?  Everything works great if I manually add the entry.id.$t string in the last if statement.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(function FISLocations() {
    $.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/GoogleSpreadsheetKey/od6/public/values? alt=json-in-script&callback=?",

      function (data) {
        $('.loc').append('<ul class="collapsibleList" id="list"><li><label for="mylist-node1" class="css_btn_classlist">Alabama</label><input type="checkbox" id="mylist-node1" /><ul class="loclist"></ul></li></ul>');
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, entry) {
          var item = '<span style="display:none ">' + entry.id.$t + '</span>';
          item += ' ' + entry.gsx$cityst.$t;
          if (entry.gsx$state.$t == "AL") {
            $('.loclist').append('<li><a href="Store.html">' + item + '</a></li>');
          };
        });

        $('.poploc').append('<div class="items"></div>');
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, entry) {
          var itemp = '<span style="display:none ">' + entry.id.$t + '</span>';
          itemp += '' + entry.gsx$address1.$t + '<br/>';
          itemp += ' ' + entry.gsx$city.$t + ', ';
          itemp += ' ' + entry.gsx$state.$t;
          itemp += ' ' + entry.gsx$postal.$t + '<br/>';
          itemp += ' ' + entry.gsx$phone.$t + '<br/>';
          itemp += ' ' + entry.gsx$fax.$t + '<br/>';
          itemp += '<div class="px12bold"> ' + entry.gsx$email.$t + '<br/ ></div>';
          itemp += '<div class="locmid"><br/><a ' + entry.gsx$androidloc.$t + 'class="css_btn_classsmall noselect">Map Us</a>';
          itemp += '<a href="mailto:' + entry.gsx$email.$t + '?subject=Message sent from FIS Outdoor App."  class="css_btn_classsmall noselect"> Email Us </a>';
          itemp += '<a href="tel:' + entry.gsx$mainphone.$t + '"  class="css_btn_classsmall noselect"> Call us </a></div>';
          if (entry.id.$t == ? ? ? ? ? ? ) {
            $('.items').append('<br>' + itemp + '</span><br/>');
          };
        });
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: entry.id.$t=localStorage.$t; then set the same localStrorage key wherever you get that info.

Comment: The row data in the first section creates multiple buttons each with data from one row.  When I tried to set up localstorage it puts the  field from the last record into storage.   How do you set the localstorage to trigger when the button is selected?